# Box-sizing property not working as expected with Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap to lay out a responsive site. I have two columns side-by-side inside a `.container` div. I would like to add a border to each side of the container. When I do so, the second column is pushed underneath the first.

```
.row {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

I thought I could correct this with the CSS `box-sizing` property to incorporate the div's border into its width. It's not working, however.

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any ideas why? **How can I add a border on each side without hacking Bootstrap's files?**

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/huV7A/13/

**Edit:** I'm trying to achieve this but with borders on the outside of the columns: http://jsfiddle.net/huV7A/12/

Comment: Can you include some more code? Your jsfiddle hardly helps. The two columns obviously aren't 50% width nor inline-block.

Comment: Remove the border and you'll see the columns lay out properly. bootstrap-combined.min.css is included in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is the same jsfiddle but with the CSS removed: http://jsfiddle.net/huV7A/10/

Comment: Still not working. I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Ah it's probably because your browser window is too small, I'll remove the responsive stylesheet... http://jsfiddle.net/huV7A/12/

Comment: Okay, it works now. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with row-fluid, here's one clean solution: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/S7pLe/

**CSS**

```
.row-fluid{
border-left:1px solid red;
border-right:1px solid red;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have placed `margin-left` on each of the two columns. Removing this immediately solves the problem.

However, this causes a problem with spacing between the border and the content; thus we add padding:

```
.span6 {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huV7A/14/

**Note**: The `margin-left` seems to be added by Bootstrap.